# How to use XSD 1.0 to ensure that only one element in sequence has child?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xsd-1.0

I have to validate the XML that may be in any one of the below form

```
<myshape>
        <dimension/>
        <mycircle>
            <radius>2</radius>
        </mycircle>
</myshape>

<myshape>
        <dimension>
            <height>5</height>
        </dimension>
        <mycircle/>
</myshape>
```

That is, only one element should contain the value and other should not.

I've tried `xs:choice`, but the problem is , I would have both elements in xml but only one should contain the child elements. How can I validate that?

Any help would be appreciated.

PS: This is an issue in legacy code, so I can't switch to XSD1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot represent your constraint in XSD 1.0  (A content model for an element cannot be based upon a value of another element.) If you cannot use XSD 1.1's assertions, then you'll have to enforce your contraint out-of-band wrt XSD.